Converting a set of parametric coordinates to Cartesian coordinates
I have the parametric set of coodinates P = $(\dfrac{1+at^{2}+6at}{4},\dfrac{3at^{2}+2at+3}{4})$ , where $a = \dfrac{1}{16}$, after solving a problem involving the locus of a point. I wish to convert this into algebraic form, but I have no clue how to eliminate $t$. I tried solving a quadratic for $t$ with the $x$ coordinate, but it's very dirty, lengthy and doesn't give the answer.
I know that this parametric coordinate is correct, as I possess the final answer, but I do not know the means to attain it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

First let's plug in $a=\frac{1}{16}$ and write the quadratic forms for $x$ and $y$ coordinates in standard form:
$$
P=\left(\frac{t^2}{64}+\frac{3t}{32}+\frac{1}{4},\frac{3t^2}{64}+\frac{t}{32}+\frac{3}{4}\right)
$$
Both coordinates are quadratic polynomials of $t$. Additionally, we have:
$$
3x-y = \frac{t}{4}
$$
From here we can plug in $3x-y$ everytime we see $\frac{t}{4}$. Let's see what this gives us for the $x$ coordinate:
$$
x = \frac{(3x-y)^2}{4} + \frac{3(3x-y)}{8}+\frac{1}{4}
$$
Equivalently:
$$
\begin{equation}
8x = 2(3x-y)^2 + (9x-3y) + 2\\
\iff 2(3x-y)^2 + (x-3y) + 2 = 0
\end{equation}
$$

$$\frac{4x-1}a=t^2+6t,\quad\frac{4y-3}a=3t^2+2t$$
$$\iff$$
$$8t^2=3\frac{4y-3}a-\frac{4x-1}a,\quad
16t=3\frac{4x-1}a-\frac{4y-3}a
$$
$$\iff$$
$$t^2=\frac{3y-x-2}{2a},\quad
t=\frac{3x-y}{4a}.
$$
Eliminating $t$, we obtain:
$$8a(3y-x-2)=(3x-y)^2,$$
i.e., since $8a=\frac12$:
$$2(3x-y)^2+x-3y+2=0.$$

I wish I could mark both the answers correct, thank you for your answer.
